# terms of service stripe connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I've created a function to create a stripe custom company account for my users, and everything is working great, but when I try and update the terms of service data in node.js, it comes up with no errors, but when I go to the Stripe dashboard it says the account still requires a terms of service acceptance. What should I do?

Here is the function that creates the account:

```js
export const createStripeMerchant = async(connectId: any, line1: any, line2: any, city: any, country: any, postCode: any,
  day: any, month: any, year: any, uid: any, email: any, firstName: any, lastName: any, phoneNumber: any) => {

  const account = await stripe.accounts.createPerson(
    connectId, {
      address: {
        line1: line1,
        line2: line2,
        city: city,
        country: country,
        postal_code: postCode,
      },
      dob: {
        day: day,
        month: month,
        year: year,
      },
      first_name: firstName,
      last_name: lastName,
      email: email,
      relationship: {
        executive: true,
        director: true,
        representative: true,
        title: 'Director',
      },
      phone: phoneNumber,
      metadata: {
        firebaseUID: uid
      },
    });

  await updateMerchantId(uid, {
    personAccountId: account.id
  });

  return account;
}
```

Here is the function that adds on the terms of service acceptance:

```
export const updateStripeConnect = async(connectId: any, uid: any, date: any, ip: any, userName: any) => {

  const account = await stripe.accounts.update(
    connectId, {
      tos_acceptance: {
        date: date,
        ip: ip,
        service_agreement: 'full',
        user_agent: userName,
      },
    }
  );
  return account;
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
createStripePerson({
  connectId: connectId,
  line1: address1.val(),
  line2: address2.val(),
  city: cityTown.val(),
  country: 'GB',
  postCode: postCode.val(),
  day: $("#dateOB").val().substring(8, 10),
  month: $("#dateOB").val().substring(5, 7),
  year: $("#dateOB").val().substring(0, 4),
  uid: uid,
  email: email.val(),
  firstName: firstName.val(),
  lastName: lastName.val(),
  phoneNumber: phoneInput.getNumber(),
}).then((result) => {
  /** @type {any} */
  const data = result.data;
  const textData = data.text;
  console.log("Result data: " + data);
  console.log("Text data: " + textData);


  updateStripeConnect({
    connectId: connectId,
    uid: uid,
    date: unixTimestamp,
    ip: ip,
    userName: firstName.val() + " " + lastName.val(),
  }).then((result) => {
    /** @type {any} */
    const data = result.data;
    const textData = data.text;
    console.log("Result data: " + data);
    console.log("Text data: " + textData);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error message: " + error.message);
    console.log("Error details: " + error.details);
  });


}).catch((error) => {
  console.log("Error message: " + error.message);
  console.log("Error details: " + error.details);
});
```

So, as I said, it all goes through, but the terms of service does not get fulfilled / is still required in Stripe's dashboard:

[image: Stripe Dashboard Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you shared that calls the Update Account [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update) looks correct overall. The main issue you have is that you are not calling it synchronously with `await` so the call is likely failing/erroring but you are not properly catching the errors.

You should start by running that code on its own with a hardcoded account id to confirm that part of the code works. Make sure to use `await` or handle the callback and also handle errors properly. Once that works, you can then add clear logs to debug the other call that isn't working for you

Comment: But of course! Thanks man, was baffling me for a while - hardcoding it and the stringifying the JSON's + adding the async/awaits did the job